# Ubuntu 14.04, Docker(left sidebar) does not show in auto hide mode on Virtual Box

Tags: unity

I have never used Linux before and I want to switch to Linux Ubuntu. I like how Unity desktop environment looks.

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version in Virtual Box and when I clicked the option to auto hide the docker(left sidebar)on it does not appear when the pointer of the mouse goes on left side of the screen.

Is it going to work properly when Ubuntu is installed on a PC instead of  Virtual machine ? Is it not working only in the virtual box ?

Comment: Did you try to get the mouse on upper left corner of the screen?

Comment: Yes I did. At the moment it's set to move the pointer on the left side and not on the top left. I tried both ways and they don't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Launcher bar "*auto hide*" option does not work on VirtualBox.

Auto hide option is  running perfectly and it's smooth when Ubuntu is installed on a PC(at least for me), instead on virtual machine.